# How i can to stop "change your password" message

Tags: google-chrome, ionic4

I'm working in a project in Ionic for my university. When i reload the app and make login i receive this message:

[image]

How i can to stop this message.

Comment: Dis you try this? https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23945619?hl=en

Comment: The steps are wrong but this helped me.

Comment: Put in the answer box, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can give you an idea [Google Chrome Support](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23945619?hl=en)